# SignalR connection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr) on how to start using SignalR.
But after I added `startup` and `chathub` and I try to run it, I get this webpage.

[image]

Do I have to configure more in my `startup` class

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Idle.Startup))]

namespace Idle
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

or what do I have to do to get SignalR working?

Thanks

Comment: If you comment out `app.MapSignalR` does the error go away? It appears to me that your request is going to MVC and you're getting an HTTP 401 there, and that it has nothing to do with SignalR.

Comment: FWIW, I downloaded the sample and tried it locally. I didn't have to do anything special to get it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded source code and works fine, I assume you are running from solution in Visual Studio:

You need to simply browse to `http://localhost:52587/Default.html` - or whatever port you are using.

Or you could right click on `Default.html` in Visual Studio and select `View in Browser`